# MongoDB aggregate query to get the Unique element list and count of every instance in record

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo, aggregation

I have a 2 collections as shown below.

data1:

```
{ "_id" : , "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-01-05T07:42:37.312Z"), "Prof_Name" : "Jack ", "SUBJECT" : "Maths, Chemistry, Machinery1, Ele1" }
{ "_id" : , "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-01-05T07:42:37.312Z"), "Prof_Name" : "Mac", "SUBJECT" : "Chemistry, CS, German" }
```

data2:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId(""), timestamp" : ISODate("2016-08-05T07:42:37.312Z", "SUBJECT_ID" : "Maths", "ID" : "OI-12", "Rating" : 6, "UUID" : 8123 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId(""), timestamp" : ISODate("2017-09-05T07:42:37.312Z", "SUBJECT_ID" : "Maths, Machinery1, German", "ID" : "OI-134", "Rating" : 6, "UUID" : 8123 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId(""), timestamp" : ISODate("2016-01-05T07:42:37.312Z", "SUBJECT_ID" : "Machinery1, Maths, French, German", "ID" : "OI-32", "Rating" : 3, "UUID" : 8123 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId(""), timestamp" : ISODate("2016-01-05T07:42:37.312Z", "SUBJECT_ID" : "CS, Chemistry", "ID" : "OI-36", "Rating" : , "UUID" : 8124 }
```

I want to get a  3 collection,between timestamp Jan 2016 to Nov 2106 where for each Prof_Name and subject  in SUBJECT from "data1", check if its present in "data2" and get the UUID and UUID count as 1,  if the same subject is found in next record make the UUID count =2 and so on. Herre is how my collection would like ..

data3:

```
{ "_id" : ,
"Prof_Name" : "Jack", 
"Subjects_list" : [ "Maths", "Chemistry", "Machinery1"], 
"UUID_list" : [8123, 8124 ], 
"UUID_count" : 3,   // Because UUID 8123 has present in 2 records which comes under 2016 timestamp
"subject_count" : 3 } // Ele1 is not mentioned because it has not been seen in any of the data2 record
{ "_id" : , 
"Prof_Name" : "Mac", 
"Subjects_list" : [ "CS"], 
"UUID_list" : [8124 ],  
"UUID_count" : 1,   // Because UUID 8123 has present in 2 records which comes under 2016 timestamp
"subject_count" : 1 }
```

The aggregated query i have is :

```
db.data1.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "SUBJECT": {
        "$split": [
          "$SUBJECT",
          ", "
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$SUBJECT"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "data2",
      "let": {
        "subject": "$SUBJECT"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$addFields": {
            "SUBJECT_ID": {
              "$split": [
                "$SUBJECT_ID",
                ", "
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$in": [
                "$$subject",
                "$SUBJECT_ID"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "UUID": 1,
            "_id": 0
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "ref_data"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$ref_data",
      "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$Prof_Name",
      "subjects_list": {
        "$addToSet": "$SUBJECT"
      },
      "UUID_list": {
        "$addToSet": "$ref_data.UUID"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "Prof_Name": "$_id",
      "UUID_count": {
        "$size": "$UUID_list"
      },
      "subject_count": {
        "$size": "$subjects_list"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$out": "data3"
  }
])
```

What modifications does this query require to get the above mentioned collection data3, mainy UUID_list and UUID-count and Subject_list.

Also want to know how to match timestamp of records given a month and year but not iso in the below query aggregate query.

Tried this :

```
    { "$project": {"year":{"$year":"$timestamp"},"month":{"$month":"$timestamp"}}},{ "$match":{"year" :"2016","month": "01"}}
```

but dint work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify aggregation with changing the subjects from comma delimited values into array in database.

For ex `"SUBJECT" : ["Maths", "", "Chemistry", "Machinery1", "Ele1"]`

You can use below aggregation.

```
db.data1.aggregate([
{"$lookup":{
  "from":"data2",
  "localField":"SUBJECT",
  "foreignField":"SUBJECT_ID",
  "as":"ref_data"
}}, // outputs all the input documents where there is any match between two subjects array.
{"$unwind":{"path":"$ref_data","preserveNullAndEmptyArrays":true}},
{"$match":{"ref_data.timestamp":{"$gte":ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"), "$lte":ISODate("2016-11-31T11:59:59.999Z")}}},
{"$addFields":{"SUBJECT":{"$setIntersection":["$SUBJECT","$ref_data.SUBJECT_ID"]}}}, // outputs the common subjects (matching) between two subjects array
{"$unwind":"$SUBJECT"},
{"$group":{
  "_id":{
    "Prof_Name":"$Prof_Name",
    "UUID":"$ref_data.UUID",
    "SUBJECT":"$SUBJECT"
  }
}},// outputs all the distinct combination of UUID and Subject
{"$group":{
  "_id":"$_id.Prof_Name",
  "UUID_count":{"$sum":1},
  "subjects_list":{"$push":"$_id.SUBJECT"},
  "UUID_distinct_list":{"$addToSet":"$_id.UUID"}
}}, // outputs the distinct uuid list, count the uuids & subjects list 
{"$addFields": {
  "Prof_Name": "$_id",
  "UUID_distinct_count": {
    "$size": "$UUID_distinct_list"
  },
  "subject_count": {
    "$size": "$subjects_list"
  }
}}, // Adds the subject list size
{"$project": {"_id": 0}},// excludes the id from final output
{"$out":"data3"}])
```

Without schema modification you can use below aggregation query.

```
db.data1.aggregate([
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"data2",
    "let":{"subject":{"$split":["$SUBJECT",", "]}},
    "pipeline":[
      {"$match": {"expr":{"$and":[{"$eq":[{"$year":"$timestamp"}, 2016]}, {"$eq":[{"$month":"$timestamp"}, 1]}]}}},
      {"$addFields":{"SUBJECT_ID":{"$split":["$SUBJECT_ID",", "]},"SUBJECT":"$$subject"}},
      {"$unwind":"$SUBJECT"},
      {"$match":{"$expr":{"$in":["$SUBJECT","$SUBJECT_ID"]}}},
      {"$facet":{
        "UUID":[{"$group":{"_id":{"id":"$_id","UUID":"$UUID"}}},{"$count":"UUID_Count"}],
        "REST":[
          {"$group":{"_id":null,"subjects_list":{"$addToSet":"$SUBJECT"},"UUID_distinct_list":{"$addToSet":"$UUID"}}},
          {"$addFields":{"subject_count":{"$size":"$subjects_list"},"UUID_distinct_count":{"$size":"$UUID_distinct_list"}}},
          {"$project":{"_id":0}}
         ]
      }},
      {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":{"$mergeObjects":[{"$arrayElemAt":["$UUID",0]},{"$arrayElemAt":["$REST",0]}]}}}
    ],
    "as":"ref_data"
  }},
  {"$unwind":{"path":"$ref_data","preserveNullAndEmptyArrays":true}},
  {"$addFields":{"ref_data.Prof_Name":"$Prof_Name"}},
  {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$ref_data"}},
  {"$out":"data3"}
])
```

Comment: query works for everything but the UUID-coun is not what i want. I want count for every occurrence for each record but this gives me unique UUID count .

Comment: Can you try now ? I've removed the group.

Comment: tried its not giving the expected output. 
Is it possible to group of ref_data.UUID and count and add it to new field something like UUID_unique ? and let UUID_count be it as in previous query:
add something like {"$group":{"_id":"$_id.UUID","UUID_unique":{"$sum":1}

Comment: Can you please update your example in the post ? The initial answer I believe matches what you have in the expected json.

Comment: initial answer also is not giving the expected UUID count (count for every single occurrence in a each record) .

Comment: This is the output I get from the initial answer. `[{ "_id" : ,
"Prof_Name" : "Jack", 
"subjects_list" : [ "Maths", "Chemistry", "Machinery1"], 
"UUID_list" : [8123, 8124 ], 
"UUID_count" : 3, 
"subject_count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : , 
"Prof_Name" : "Mac", 
"subjects_list" : [ "German", "CS", "Chemistry"], 
"UUID_list" : [8124, 8123 ],  
"UUID_count" : 3,
"subject_count" : 3 }]` Is this not expected ?

Comment: Thank you @Veeram the third aggregate query did what i wanted. 
Also i update the question to match record based on time with respect to "Year" and Month but not ISO date. How do i modify the query

Comment: You are welcome. I've just updated the answer.. Please use second aggregate query.

Comment: Add timestamp to both the facet stages i.e `{"$facet":{
        "UUID":[{"$group":{"_id":{"id":"$_id","UUID":"$UUID"}, timestamp:{$first:"$timestamp"}},{"$group":{"_id":null,"timestamp":{"$first":"$timestamp"},"UUID_Count":{"$sum":1}}}],
        "REST":[
          {"$group":{"_id":null,"subjects_list":{"$addToSet":"$SUBJECT"},timestamp:{$first:"$timestamp"}}, "UUID_distinct_list":{"$addToSet":"$UUID"}}},
          {"$addFields":{"subject_count":{"$size":"$subjects_list"},"UUID_distinct_count":{"$size":"$UUID_distinct_list"}}},
          {"$project":{"_id":0}}
         ]
      }}`